# OData function routing conventions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I have been studying OData for a while and I am facing a specific requirement which I couldn't find a solution for, which is calling a function in OData with the parameters surrounded by slashes, in other words, I need to accomplish this: /entity/key/functionName/param1/param2/param3/ I have tried using `[RoutePrefix("/entity/{key}/functionName/{param1}/{param2}..."]`
without any success.
The action was like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult functionName(int key, int param1, int param2...)
```

I know that you can have this result by using `[RoutePrefix("/entity({key}/functionName(param1={param1}....)`. But this is not what I want.

Does anybody has any idea if is it accomplishable?

Answer (score 2):

OData is effectively a specification for how to communicate with a webservice. It defines how to sort, select and filter but also how to call functions. What you are suggesting here is to call a function but not in the way that OData specifies so asking whether it can be done in OData doesn't really make any sense. I would either try and achieve it separately from OData, i.e. just using regular Web.API or try use the existing OData format, otherwise you will need to rewrite a large part of the OData library

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom, do you know if I can achieve at least something like in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343559/how-to-create-a-sub-resource-using-odata-without-creating-a-collection-propert                                    Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems like the same problem to me - if you want to change the way that URLs are constructed, you are no longer using OData