# How to create a "sub-resource" using OData without creating a collection property for it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm creating a Web API 2 using `OData v4` to provide the following HTTP verbs for my models: `GET`, `POST` and `PUT`, which means that for each resource (model class) I can *insert/update/retrieve* data from the following URLs:

- /api/myResourceName
- /api/myResourceName/{id}

And for my sub-resources (the children models) I can do the same through the following URLs:

- /api/myResourceName/{id}/subresource
- /api/myResourceName/{id}/subresource/{subresourceId}

However, in order to have a sub-resource, I necessarily need to have an `IEnumerable<MySubresourceModel>` in the `ResourceModel`, but there are many cases in which I don't want it because it'll be visible through the "medatata url (`/api/$metadata`) as a collection but I don't allow these items to be *created / updated / retrieved* in the actions of the "resource model" itself.

Example:

In order to have the `GET /api/people/10/addresses/5` action working, I must have:

The model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    // Without this property the API even doesn't run
    public IEnumerable<AddressModel> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

OData configuration:

```
modelConfiguration.AddEntity<PersonModel>("people");
modelConfiguration.AddEntity<AddressModel>("addresses");
```

The controller:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("people/{personId}/addresses")]
public class PeopleAddressesController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQueryDefault]
    [ODataRoute("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int personId, int id)
    {
        // [...]
    }

    // [...]
}
```

But when I don't have the property `Addresses` in the `PersonModel`, an  exception is thrown when the application starts:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The path template 'people/{personId}/addresses' on the action 'Ge*' in
>   controller 'PeopleAddresses' is not a valid OData path template. Found
>   an unresolved path segment 'addresses' in the OData path template
>   'people/{personId}/addresses'.

The question is: **How can I have sub-resources without having the collection property?**

PS: I've already tried using OData `Actions` and `Functions` but that didn't work for me.